# SQL Select query to select data between to dates where from date month is higher than the to date month and year difference is >1

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I want to select all the records from a table where the query params is something  like:

from_month: 09

to_month : 03

from year: 2011

to_year: 2014

I am trying the below query:

```
Select * from Table 
where month(created_at) between '09' and '03' 
     and year(created_at) between '2011' and '2014'
```

Although the data is there it returns me zero records as the from_month is greater than the to month.

I even tried the query to directly compate the dates instead of month and year seperately, but it still returns me zero records.

Comment: Put up your table structure please

Comment: from_month or from_date? or to_date or to_month?

Comment: Select * from Table 
where (month(created_at) >=9 OR month(created_at) <=3) 
     and year(created_at) between 2011 and 2014 ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it? I think You are between done this way. Its got maximum to minimum between

```
where month(created_at) between '09' and '03'
```

instead

```
where month(created_at) between '03' and '09'
```

or Use greater than and less than way

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE month(created_at)>='09' AND month(created_at)<='11'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query fails for two reasons. First, `between` needs to have lower limit first, then the upper one. `beween 9 and 3` will therefore always get you `0` records.
Second, it will miss for example the records between `'2012-01-01'` and `'2012-02-28'` and the records between `'2012-10-01'` and `'2013-02-28'`.

Don't make it more complicated as it is.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2011-09-01' AND '2014-03-31'
```

It's also better to do it this way, since MySQL can not use indexes on the columns where you apply a function.

If you don't know, if the upper date's day is 30, 31, 28 or even 29, you can do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2011-09-01' AND LAST_DAY('2014-03-01');
```

Also note, that you have to append a time, when your `created_at` column is of type timestamp or datetime. Otherwise you'll miss the last day's records.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2011-09-01' AND '2014-03-31 23:59:59'
```

When you don't append a time, it automatically becomes `00:00:00`, therefore you'd miss `2014-03-31`.